# Pass change to child components when data value in parent component is changed in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, parent-child

I want to pass down the changes made in parent component data values to its child components each time the value changes in parent how can i achieve it in vue.js. I am using 3 custom components that have to reflect the current value of the parent component each time. p.s i am new to vue.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is typically passed one-way from parent to child components via props. See the [documentation on this here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props).

Example:

```
// register the child component 
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['myProp'],
  template: '<span>{{ myProp }}</span>'
})

// in parent component 
<child :my-prop="hello"></child>
```

Comment: it worked i was having an issue with it  ur solution seems to work thank you

Answer (score 2):

you just need to pass it as a prop. In your template:

```
<my-component :my-prop="myData" />
```

and in your script tag:

```
export default {
  data() {
    myData: 0,
  }
}
```

Whenever you update `this.data`, the component will update its view, as the prop will have changed